# Passing a table name as a query parameter in Ms-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a access database that is composed of multiple tables with the same structure. What I am trying to do is use a combo box on a form to select the table and then execute a query with the chosen table name.

The query would be the same except for the table name that's being used.

I'm having trouble passing the table name from the combo box to the query.

I know its probably not the best database structure but its what I need to do. If anyone has any advice to share that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code where you're building the query? just don't escape the name...

Comment: I don't have much to show. I was attempting to do it with sql because my VBA skills are kind of basic. What I was trying was SELECT table.[fieldname], but where I chose table I need to pass the table name selected from the dropdown menu called "tableSelect"

Comment: well, you can work with an event `onChange` or `afterUpdate` on the combobox to access it's properties and run the query there...

Comment: `t.[fieldname], ... FROM [" & me.combo1 & "] As t` I hope you have a lot of confidence in your users.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply do that using a pre compiled SQL Query. You need a little bit of VBA to get it going, this is how you would do it.

Create a Form with one ComboBox and one button.

Name the ComboBox as **tableNameCombo** and the button as **runQueryBtn**. Save the Form, with the name **frm_QueryRun**.

Create a new Query something along the lines of,

```
SELECT * FROM randomTableName;
```

Save this as **qry_Tmp**.

Now go back to Form design, then on Property sheet of the **Form**, look for the Current Method. Then paste the following code into the Form Current.

**Note**: If this is your First VBA, check out : http://www.baldyweb.com/FirstVBA.htm

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim tblStr As String
    Dim dbObj As DAO.Database, tdObj As DAO.TableDef

    Set dbObj = CurrentDB()

    Me.tableNameCombo.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    For Each tdObj In db.TableDefs
        If Left(tdObj.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then tblStr = tblStr & tdObj.Name & ";"
    Next

    tblStr = Left(tblStr, Len(tblStr)-1)
    Me.tableNameCombo.RowSource = tblStr
    Set dbObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Once this is done, you would need to construct your qry_Tmp. something like, on the click of the button.

```
Private Sub runQueryBtn_Click()
    Dim dbObj As DAO.Database, qdObj As DAO.QueryDef
    If Me.tableNameCombo.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Table Name needs to be selected, before continuing.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set dbObj = CurrentDB()
    Set qdObj = dbObj.QueryDefs("qry_Tmp")

    qdObj.SQL = "SELECT " & Me.tableNameCombo & ".* FROM " & Me.tableNameCombo & ";"

    qdObj.Execute dbFailOnError

    qdObj.Close
    Set qdObj = Nothing
    Set dbObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Save the Form, Close it, compile the code for any error. Then run the code. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is really helpful. I encountered this problem when I wanted to pass column names and table name as parameters to Access SQL query. Do you know if that could work at all?