# Passing a table name in a Form to be used within a Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Here is the code I am using, which I found: [Passing a table name as a query parameter in Ms-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164526/passing-a-table-name-as-a-query-parameter-in-ms-access)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim tblStr As String
    Dim dbObj As DAO.Database, tdObj As DAO.TableDef

    Set dbObj = CurrentDb()
    Me.tableNameCombo.RowSourceType = "SELECT ProductRecipeList.[Product Recipe Name] FROM ProductRecipeList; "
    For Each tdObj In db.TableDefs
        If Left(tdObj.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then tblStr = tblStr & tdObj.Name & ";"
    Next

    tblStr = Left(tblStr, Len(tblStr) - 1)
    Me.tableNameCombo.RowSource = tblStr
    Set dbObj = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub runQueryBtn_Click()
    Dim dbObj As DAO.Database, qdObj As DAO.QueryDef
    If Me.tableNameCombo.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Table Name needs to be selected, before continuing.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set dbObj = CurrentDb()
    Set qdObj = dbObj.QueryDefs("qry_Tmp")

    qdObj.SQL = "SELECT " & Me.tableNameCombo & ".* FROM " & Me.tableNameCombo & ";"

    qdObj.Execute dbFailOnError
```

However, I am unable to dine the method/data
[image]

But I can see it within Expression field: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

- Verified Name of Control Box [image]
- Verified Data existed within 'Me'

Comment: Don't need table qualifier prefix in those simple SQL statements. `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: Why do you need to change source table of query object? Multiple tables of same structure as described other question? Indicates a poorly designed db.

Comment: You are setting the RowSourceType property incorrectly. Look at the original code again.